# Is it possible to use the temporary object of a with-statement as a parameter for a function?

Tags: vba, with-statement

I use a with statement in VBA like this:

```
With New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    'Some statements
end with
```

and I have got a sub like this:

```
Private Sub anyfunction(ByVal par_document As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)

end sub
```

Is there a way to use the the temporary object as the parameter for the anyfunction or do I have to create a variable with "Dim" in order to use the anyfunction?

Comment: What temporary variable are you referring to? If you can refer to it then you can pass it. I don't think you have any way to refer to it, though `Me` might be a natural guess.

Comment: The one (of type  MSXML2.DOMDocument60) which is created by the with statement.

Comment: That is an object, not a variable

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: It is an interesting question. I think that the answer is no, but even if it were yes, I would still use a variable for clarity.

Comment: No, there is no way to refer to an object inside `With...End With` block (except using its name), so in this case it is not possible at all (unless a specific class implements a reference to itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the object provides a reference to it self, use that. For`MSXML2.DOMDocument60`you can use`.SelectSingleNode("/")`or use a child-object with a reference to the parent-object. (e.g.`.documentElement.ownerDocument`or`.childNodes(0).parentNode`, but they need a XML-Document loaded.)
Or the opposite (parent to child) for`Dao.Recordset`use`.Parent.RecordSets(.Name)`.

```vb
With New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    .Load("xmlfile")
    anyfunction(.SelectSingleNode("/"))
end with
```

Comment: Does it answer the question? OP wants to pass the whole `DOMDocument60`, but he can't pass it with `With`.

Comment: @JohnyL `.SelectSingleNode("/")`returns the`MSXML2.DOMDocument60`. To test use `Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60; If doc.SelectSingleNode("/") Is doc then Debug,Print "Same object"`.